# Number Fields have nonzero discriminant

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the following proof correct?

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(a)$ and suppose disc $K = 0$. This means that there exists a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis $b_1,b_2,\cdots, b_n$ of $K$ such that the matrix with entries $\sigma_i(b_j)$ is singular. This means that there exist constants $c_i$, which are in $K$ by the Gauss-Jordan row reduction, such that $\sum_i c_i \sigma_i(b_j) = 0$ for all $j$, hence $\sum_i c_i \sigma_i = 0$ identically, hence $\sum_i c_i \sigma_i(a^j) = 0$ for all $j$. But this is $\sum_i c_i a_i^j = 0$, so the matrix with entries $a_i^j$ is singular, contradicting the fact that it's a Vandermonde determinant (and that the minimal polynomial of $a$ is separable). $\blacksquare$

Comment: yes it is correct but realy you only need the fact that the minimal polynomial is separable using expression of discrimininant in terms of the roots

Comment: what is this expression?

Comment: if the roots of the polynomial are $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ then the discriminant of the polynomial  is $\Pi_{i<j} (\alpha_i-\alpha_j)^2$

Comment: is it true that the discriminant of Q(a) is equal to the discriminant of the minimal polynomial of a?

Comment: if $a$ also generate the ring of integers of $Q(a)$ yes they are equal. in general it compute discriminant of $Q[a]$ but as you said for computing discriminant you have to choose a $Z$ basis for the ring of integers $b_1,...,b_n$ but there is an invertible matrix such that $(b_i)=A(a_i)$ so if discriminant of minimal polynomial is nonzero the discriminant of field is also nonzero